# Objects created from extruded planes boolean problems

Tags: modifiers, objects

I duplicate standard cube and scale down copy. Use copy to do boolean difference cut in original cube. Everything works fine.

But if I create  similar size cube by extruding a rectangular plane and try same boolean OP nothing works.
What's difference between a standard 3d mesh cube and a cube or any other 3d object that is created by extrusion from a 2d plane?

How can you turn objects created by extrusion into normal 3d objects that behave like they should?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you extrude a plane, you have one chance out of two to have inverted normals, depending on the direction you choose. If the boolean object has inverted normals it won't work. So try to recalculate the normals, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in *Edit* mode.

[image]

Comment: +1 - but how did you calculate the probability that quick!? Can u explain this mathematically? 

Comment: well, do you know a bit of quantic physics and the Schrödinger's cat?

Comment: yes, you never know whether the cat eats the mouse or not ;)

Comment: it's a bit like Heisenberg....which is essentially: you never know... :D

Comment: exactly, so when you extrude you never know if the normals are inverted or not, which makes Blender quite dangerous to work with, it can explode any time  ://

Comment: BE AWARE OF THAT CHRIS!!!!!!!!

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!! But...because we are living in a simulation....nothing can happen...or everything ;)

Comment: Thanks for info inverted normals seem to solve prob. Been stuck in parallel universe where blender is hell and nothing worked for past few weeks.  Now back in this reality such as it is